# How do I know that I already single sign-on in angular application?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I use https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/configuration.md to setup a single sign-on in angular. So if I click the sign in button then I can login.

My question is that if in other place I already login with my company's credentials so I don't need to login again in the angular application. How my angular application knows I already signed? Therefore I don't need navigation to login component and click sign in button again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The msal-browser library provides the following APIs to access cached accounts:
>
> - `getAllAccounts()`: returns all the accounts currently in the cache. An application must choose an account to acquire tokens silently.
> - `getAccountByHomeId()`: receives a `homeAccountId` string and returns the matching account from the cache.
> - `getAccountByLocalId()`: receives a `localAccountId` string and returns the matching account from the cache.
> - `getAccountByUsername()`: receives a username string and returns the matching account from the cache.
>
> [ ... snip ... ]
>
> The current [`msal-browser` default sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/VanillaJSTestApp2.0) has a working single account scenario.

Source: [Accounts in MSAL Browser](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/accounts.md).

*Part of that example code:*

```js
const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

myMSALObj.handleRedirectPromise().then(handleResponse).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});

function handleResponse(resp) {
    if (resp !== null) {
        accountId = resp.account.homeAccountId;
        myMSALObj.setActiveAccount(resp.account);
        showWelcomeMessage(resp.account);
    } else {
        const currentAccounts = myMSALObj.getAllAccounts();
        if (!currentAccounts || currentAccounts.length < 1) {
            return;
        } else if (currentAccounts.length === 1) {
            const activeAccount = currentAccounts[0];
            myMSALObj.setActiveAccount(activeAccount);
            accountId = activeAccount.homeAccountId;
            showWelcomeMessage(activeAccount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you meant when the user login outside angular, the information can be cached somewhere? Then inside angular we can retrieve the cached information by certain methods? So where is the cache?